# CNN Model With Low Accuracy

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network, image-recognition

I'm currently working on a CNN model that classifies food images. So far, I have managed to build a functioning CNN but I would like to improve the accurracy. For the dataset, I have used some images from Kaggle and few from my own collection.

Here is some information about the dataset:

1. There are 91 classes of food images.
2. Each class has around 500 to 650 images.
3. The dataset has been manually cleaned and checked for unrelated or bad quality images (*the photos are of different sizes*).

Here is my CNN model:

```
classifier = Sequential()

def cnn_layer_creation(classifier):

classifier.add(InputLayer(input_shape=[224,224,3]))

classifier.add(Conv2D(filters=32,kernel_size=5,strides=1,padding='same',activation='relu',data_format='channels_first'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=5,padding='same'))

classifier.add(Conv2D(filters=50,kernel_size=5,strides=1,padding='same',activation='relu'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=5,padding='same'))

classifier.add(Conv2D(filters=80,kernel_size=5,strides=1,padding='same',activation='relu',data_format='channels_last'))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=5,padding='same'))

classifier.add(Dropout(0.25))
classifier.add(Flatten())
classifier.add(Dense(64,activation='relu'))
classifier.add(Dropout(rate=0.5))
classifier.add(Dense(91,activation='softmax'))

# Compiling the CNN
classifier.compile(optimizer="RMSprop", loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', metrics = ['accuracy'])
data_initialization(classifier)

def data_initialization(classifier):

# Part 2 - Fitting the CNN to the images

from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
                                   shear_range = 0.2,
                                   zoom_range = 0.2,
                                   horizontal_flip = True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
                                  shear_range = 0.2,
                                  zoom_range = 0.2,
                                  horizontal_flip = True)

training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('food_image/train',
                                                 target_size = (224, 224),
                                                 batch_size = 100,
                                                 class_mode = 'categorical')

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('food_image/test',
                                            target_size = (224, 224),
                                            batch_size = 100,
                                            class_mode = 'categorical')

classifier.fit_generator(training_set,
                         steps_per_epoch = 100,
                         epochs = 100,
                         validation_data = test_set,
                         validation_steps = 100)

classifier.save("brynModelGPULite.h5")
classifier.summary()

def main():

cnn_layer_creation(classifier)
```

*Training is done on GPU (nVidia 980M)*

Unfortunately, the accuracy has not exceeded 10%. Things I've tried are:

1. Increase the number of epochs.
2. Change the optimizer (ADAM, RMSPROP).
3. Change the activation function.
4. Reduce the image input size.
5. Increase the batch size.
6. Change the filter size to 32, 64, 128.

None of these have improved the accuracy.

Could anyone shine some light on how I might improve my model accuracy?

Comment: Please *format* your code appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

You can augment only the training data.

**The following code**

```
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
                                      shear_range = 0.2,
                                      zoom_range = 0.2,
                                      horizontal_flip = True)
```

**should be**

```
test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I assume you are building your model from scratch. As such training on fewer epochs(I assume you would not have trained your model for more than 1000 epochs), will not help as the network would not evolve completely because the representations would not have been completely learnt in so few epochs when you train a model from scratch. You can try increasing the number of epochs to around 10000 and see. Rather why not try and use transfer learning for the same, additionally you can also using feature extraction and fine tuning or both using a pre trained convnet. For reference you can have a look at chapter 5 in the book by Francois Chollet titled Deep Learning with Python.

Comment: I've tried transfer learning as well but doesn't get above 59%. I would go for 10000 epoch but the learning stops between 20-30 epoch so I assume that it is just a waste of resource and time. Moreover, I can't use transfer learning here as this is a college project. Thanks for your answer by the way.

Comment: Could you try adding more layers and see the result?

Comment: Also, u have set your batch size to 100 and steps per epoch to 100 that means in one epoch a max of 10000 different images. I believe your model should being seeing the entire set of images in your training data, don't you think?

Comment: Comment 1:  
Do you mean duplicate the (Max Pooling and Conv2D) layers? If so, should I increase the filter size or leave it as it is?

Comment: Yeah add more layers and also take a look at your batch size(my second comment)

Comment: I started a new training process with 2 extra (Conv2D and MaxPooling) layers and with batch size of 520 and 20 for epoch. This is what i get. Link : [Trained Result Image](https://i.imgur.com/KcKyO6U.png) . Not much learning happening here after epoch 15. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What is your batch size and batches per epoch value?

Comment: I have 51,841 images so I change the ||
batch size = 520 ||
steps_per_epoch = 100 ||
epoch = 20

Comment: Try k fold cross validation with various training parameters, also can you change the max pool kernel size to 2 or 3 and see the results. For k fold cross validation use various steps per epoch, total number of epochs, batch size, optimizers etc

Comment: Hi Shubam. Got your suggestion but could you suggest any links or site where I can loom the structure how K-Fold is done in Keras? Because of the too many examples not sure which one is safe and worth following and I did had a hard time understanding some of them.

Comment: Have a look at this link from kaggle https://www.kaggle.com/stefanie04736/simple-keras-model-with-k-fold-cross-validation

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem with another dataset and I replaced the flatten layer with `globalAveragepooling` and it solved the problem.

I'm not sure this is going to work for you but as my model has a structure similar to yours, I think this can help you. But the difference is that I trained my model for 3 classes.